# Anchor tags are not working in Tizen Web App

Tags: html, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am creating a Tizen Web App for wearable device and i want to route to a certain point on a separate page but anchor tags don't seem to be working. They route me to the page, but just to the top of the page.

I've tried these 3 options, the first one routes me to the top of the page no matter how far down the tag is and the other two don't work at all.

I've also tried doing it with the second page in a seperate HTML using href="flags.html#A" and this also routed to the top of the page.

I also tried using 'name' instead of 'id' and a 'div' tag in place of an 'a' tag with the same results.

```
<div class="ui-page ui-page-active" id="main">
    <div class="ui-content">
      <ul class="ui-listview">
          <li><a href="#flags">A
              <i>Alfa</i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#flags#B">B
              <i>Bravo</i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#flagsC">C
              <i>Charlie</i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-page" id="flags">
    <header class="ui-header">
        <h2 class="ui-title">Select Flag</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="ui-content">
        <a id="A">A-Alfa</a><br>
            <a><b>International Call Signals</b><br>I have a diver down; keep well clear at slow speed</a><br>
        <a id="B">B-Bravo</a><br>
            <a><b>International Call Signals</b><br></a><br>
        <a id="flagsC">C-Charlie</a><br>
            <a><b>International Call Signals</b><br>Affirmative</a><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated

Comment: Remove the # from anchor tags. Just write YourFileName.html, where YourFileName is your landing page.

Comment: Not sure why the first and third aren't working for you, but change the second anchor tag from ```<a href="#flags#B">``` to ```<a href="#B">```

Comment: @RohanRao, i can get it to go to the landing page, but it just goes to the top, not to the position on the page where the anchor tag is.

Comment: @ShivamPuri, Thanks, but the button doesn't do anything at that point. I tried it with the id in the second page in the same file as well as in the other file, neither works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the cleanest solution but i ended up using a javascript function to achieve my goal.

```
function loadPage2(flagSelection) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("flagSelected", flagSelection);
    location.href="flagsPage.html";
}
```

triggered by;

```
<li><a onclick=loadPage2("#A");>A
    <i>Alfa</i></a></li>
<li><a onclick=loadPage2("#B");>B
    <i>Bravo</i></a></li>
<li><a onclick=loadPage2("#C");>C
    <i>Charlie</i></a></li>
```

and on the second page;

```
var flagSelection = window.localStorage.getItem("flagSelected");

function jumpToFlag() {
    location.href="#";
    location.href=flagSelection;
}

const load = () => {
    console.log("load event detected!");
}   
window.onload = jumpToFlag();
```